# How do I create a new column in an Oracle SQL database that is boolean and if a string entry in another column contains "100g" put a 1. Else, put a 0

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datatables

I have this big table here in SQL in an automated database in the Oracle Cloud. I created another column called portion_size. I want to create a script that scans the description and if it contains "100g", I want to put a 1 in the portion_size column. Else, I want to put a 0. I think I need to do something with the CONTAINS command and the CASE commands. I am not sure how to put it all together though. I am new to SQL.

[Here is the table I am working with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0X9D.png)

How do I write this?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If your version of Oracle allows it, consider using a virtual column for this (examples [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)).  Once this is in place, you don't need to UPDATE every time you INSERT a new row into the table (or: calculate the value for the portion_size column before the insert).

You can add a virtual column to the existing table by using ALTER TABLE ...

```
alter table vcdemo2
add portion_size number as (
    CASE WHEN LOWER(DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%100g%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) virtual ;
```

See [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f59d4e5090bc9406fdbcaf0a34f44a5e) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem, I believe.

```
UPDATE NUTRITION
SET PORTION_SIZE = (CASE WHEN LOWER(DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%100g%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END);
```